# Margin attribute in CSS is not working for input tag

Tags: input, width, padding, margin, display

[In this image, I am facing problem. I have written code in CSS for centering the search box and tried to design it, but it is not getting changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwTkx.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1CsC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DceVp.jpg)

Comment: .serach-box{
    display:block;
    width: min-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

Comment: I wrote this CSS code, but it is not working in my browser. It not changing the style of search box.